# How to call common app for many WAR file by writing it at single Place?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, tomcat6, web.xml

I have many applications deployed in Tomcat webapps directory say A, B and C.

Also there is one separate Utility Project say Z that needs to be Used by all A,B and C.

So one way to do this is putting the .class file of Z project in classes folder of all A,B and C project.

Is it possible to keep the Z project there it is and we can just give a reference for the same Z project in A, B and C, So that we don't need to copy the jar or .class files at all 3 project.

if Yes, How to do this?

I am sorry if I asked silly question....but want to clear the doubt.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Web applications are isolated into distinct [class loaders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader). This way, classes and libs of an app are not affecting another app. If you want to share classes or libs between applications, you can place them in the common class loader.

From [Tomcat 6 Class Loader How-To](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)

> ```
>   Bootstrap
>       |
>    System
>       |
>    Common
>    /     \
> ```
>
> Webapp1   Webapp2 ...

Have also a look at [Shared Library Files](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html#Shared_Library_Files).

That said, it is not necessary a best practice since it complexifies the deployment of tomcat itself; it means that the `.war` is not really "stand-alone"; and it might break the isolation model of web apps (see the note below).

What you have is build issue. You could use a build system, like [maven](http://maven.apache.org/), to automate the build of your `.war`. Each project A, B, C can depend on a common project D. When you build A, B, or C, the build system builds D first, then package everything according to your need.

Note:

Web app should be isolated so that they don't share objects. Their object graph is completely distinct and each app can be easily redeployed (and garbage collected) individually. If you put classes in a common class loader, it might introduce unwanted side-effect. For instance, if the shared class implements a singleton, it means that all apps will share the same instance of the singleton object, which conflict with the assumed isolation model. Usually people share classes this way when they explicitely want to share objects between app in some exceptional case.

Comment: Thanks Ewernli, it cleared my doubt to some extent. 
Let me go through the link you mentioned.

Actually this question was ask to me in some interview and I want some small application to test that kind of piece..Thanks